# git checkout master does not restore files

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I have a repo, being at master. I do `git checkout -b new_branch` and change, add and commit some files to `new_branch`. Doing `git checkout master` keep the files state as they were in `new_branch`, so I have to do a `git checkout -- .` on `master` to get all files to `master` state.

If I now change back and forth between the branches everything is updated like I expect them to. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This seems to be a bug with Atom, the text editor I am using. See [this issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4982)

Comment: Are the files kept from new_branch (when you switch to master) private files? (ie, files that were new, not yet committed)

Comment: @VonC yes, they are kept. I have tested a bit but it looks like it doesn't always happen. It actually seems that atom (the text editor) may _some times_ not release the file upon a checkout. Most times the file is changed on the fly also in the text editor. I'm confused... Doing a lot of switching between branches is able to reproduce the problem, but I cannot pin point when or why it is happening.

Comment: Are those files *new files* though?

Comment: @VonC Those are new files, created when I am on `new_branch`. I do `git checkout new_branch`, `touch new_file.h`, `git checkout master`. Please see the EDIT update in original question. It seems to be a bug with Atom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how Git behaves, but rather a [bug in Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4982), which does not update the file buffers in the editor.

The files are properly updated in the working tree by Git.